# Perl IO::Uncompress::Unzip

Tags: perl, unzip

I'm trying to understand how to use IO::Uncompress::Unzip in order to uncompress Jar files. I've got the names of the files in the jar printing, but I am getting the error:

```
Can't call method "reset" on an undefined value at ../IO/Uncompress/Base.pm line 986.
```

after I read the last entry. Here's my module:

```
sub modify_artifact {
    my %parameters = @_;

    my @required_parameters = qw( version directory );

    for my $parameter ( @required_parameters ) {
        if ( not exists $parameters{$parameter} ) {
            die qq(ERROR: Missing required parameter "$parameter");
        }
    }
    my $directory = $parameters{directory};

    my $dir_fh = IO::Dir->new( $parameters{directory} ) or
        die qq(ERROR: Cannot open directory "$parameters{directory} for reading.);

    while ( my $file_name  = $dir_fh->read ) {
        next if $file_name =~ /^\./;             #Hidden and "." and ".."
        my $full_file_name = File::Spec->join( $directory, $file_name );
        my $archive_fh = IO::Uncompress::Unzip->new( $full_file_name ) or
            die qq(ERROR: Cannot open file "$full_file_name" for reading.);
        while ( my $status = $archive_fh->nextStream ) {
            last unless $status > 0;
            say $archive_fh->getHeaderInfo->{Name};   # Print out file or directory
        }
    }

}
```

The `say` line is working for each and every entry in the archive, but then I get a failure when attempting to read in the next stream:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.vegicorp/
META-INF/maven/com.vegicorp/services/
META-INF/maven/com.vegicorp/services/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/com.vegicorp/services/pom.xml
com/
com/vegicorp/
com/vegicorp/services/
com/vegicorp/services/filter/
com/vegicorp/services/filter/impl/
com/vegicorp/services/generators/
com/vegicorp/services/filter/impl/DescInfoFilter.class
com/vegicorp/services/filter/impl/RequestFilterAals.class
com/vegicorp/services/generators/OutputGenerator$1.class
com/vegicorp/services/generators/OutputGenerator.class  <- Last entry in archive
Can't call method "reset" on an undefined value at ../IO/Uncompress/Base.pm line 986.
```

I've tried the `for` loop shown in the examples too:

```
sub modify_artifact {
    my %parameters = @_;

    my @required_parameters = qw( version directory );

    for my $parameter ( @required_parameters ) {
        if ( not exists $parameters{$parameter} ) {
            die qq(ERROR: Missing required parameter "$parameter");
        }
    }
    my $directory = $parameters{directory};

    my $dir_fh = IO::Dir->new( $parameters{directory} ) or
        die qq(ERROR: Cannot open directory "$parameters{directory} for reading.);

    while ( my $file_name  = $dir_fh->read ) {
        next if $file_name =~ /^\./;             #Hidden and "." and ".."
        my $full_file_name = File::Spec->join( $directory, $file_name );
        my $archive_fh = IO::Uncompress::Unzip->new( $full_file_name ) or
            die qq(ERROR: Cannot open file "$full_file_name" for reading.);
        my $status;
        for ($status = 1; $status > 0; $status = $archive_fh->nextStream()) {
            say $archive_fh->getHeaderInfo->{Name};
            last if $status < 0;
        }
    }

}
```

But I get the same issue. It appears that the `nextStream` method is causing the error. Is there something I'm missing here? Is there a way to see if there is a next stream before I fetch it?

Comment: Do you specifically need to use IO::Uncompress::Unzip?  Archive::Zip and Archive::Extract have much more pleasant interfaces.

Comment: That may be true, but `IO::Uncompress::Unzip` comes with Perl while the others are optional modules that must be installed with CPAN. I'd rather use standard modules when available since I know they'll be there no matter which computer I'm on.

Comment: Just tried the equivalent of what you are doing on a random jar file. Worked fine. What version of IO::Uncompress::Unzip are you running?

Comment: @pmqs I found the issue. My program has no problems with jars or zips. It is failing because I am downloading the JAR file and the matching POM. It's failing when I am trying to go through the POM as a ZIP archive. `IO::Uncompress::Unzip` returns a valid GLOB reference by default when opening a non-zip file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

Each directory has two files in it: One is the POM, and one is the jar (zip) file. My outer `$dir_fh->read` loop goes though the directory, it first picks up the jar, then the POM.

First time through, the inner loop first gets the jar file, opens it with `IO::Uncompress::Unzip`. The inner loop has no problems and exits as expected.

The outer loop now gets the POM file, and passes that to `IO::Uncompress::Unzip` to open. `IO::Uncompress::Unzip->new` returns a zero status -- even though this isn't a zip file. However, the `$archive_fh->nextStream` is croaking because there is no next stream to fetch.

Since I don't have any indication that a new file had been open, I never detected that the POM was being opened and using `nextStream` on that was causing my program to croak.

So, `IO::Uncompress:Unzip->new` opens uncompressed files as if they're zip files, and returns a valid file handle.

Reading through the Perldoc, I found this under constructor options:

> - Transparent => 0|1
>      
>     If this option is set and the input file/buffer is not compressed data, the module will allow reading of it anyway.
>     In addition, if the input file/buffer does contain compressed data and there is non-compressed data immediately following it, setting this option will make this module treat the whole file/buffer as a single data stream.
>      
>     This option defaults to 1.

Okay, by default, `IO::Uncompress::Unzip` opens non-zip files for reading. If I want to end this behavior, I need to do this:

```
my $archive_fh = IO::Uncompress::Unzip->new( 
    $full_file_name, 
    Transparent => 0,
) or die qq(ERROR: Cannot open file "$full_file_name" for reading.);
```

This won't open my POM as a ZIP, and the program works.